# AWS - Creating Read Replica of a Read Replica

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

We are migrating our MySql instance from version 5.5 in US to 5.6 in Sydney.
To reduce downtime I want to do following:

1. Create Readonly Replica in US
2. Upgrade it to 5.6
3. Enable automated Backup as it's required to replicate the instance
4. PROBLEM: When I'm trying to create a replica of a replica(selecting Sydney as destination region) I get this: "*The source DB instance specified needs to be non read replica*"

If I understand this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html correctly it should be perfectly fine for me to create a replica of a replica, however I'm running out of ideas why it doesn't let me... Should I make it non-readonly?

**UPDATE:** It looks like you can create a Replica(5.6) of a Read Replica(5.6) in the same region, however I still have no luck creating a readReplica from a readReplica in another region.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the step of **Promoting the Read Replica to fully functional stand-alone RDS instance**.

Once you are through this step, you can then enable the Backups and Snapshots.

**Excerpt From AWS Blog**

> Upgrade Support
>
> Today we are enhancing Amazon RDS with the ability to upgrade your
>   MySQL DB Instances from version 5.5 to the latest release in the 5.6
>   series that's available on RDS.
>
> **To upgrade your existing instances, create a new Read Replica, upgrade it to MySQL 5.6, and once it has caught up to your existing
>   master, promote it to be the new master.** You can initiate and
>   monitor each of these steps from the AWS Management Console. Refer to
>   the Upgrading from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.6 section of the Amazon RDS
>   User Guide to learn more.

References : [MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.6 Upgrade Support for Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/mysql-55-to-mysql-56-upgrade-support-for-amazon-rds/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20AmazonWebServicesBlog%20%28Amazon%20Web%20Services%20Blog%29)

Comment: I really hope this is not needed as I still need to have only one master and 2 replicas to start with. "_When creating a read replica, there are a few things to consider. First, you must enable automatic backups on the source DB instance by setting the backup retention period to a value other than 0. This requirement also applies to a read replica that is the source DB instance for another read replica_"

Comment: @Kostya : I have updated my answer with AWS blog link explaining the update process from 5.5 to 5.6. I guess promoting the RR to instance is must.

Comment: I really hope that this is not the answer because of this: "You can create multiple read replicas for a given source DB instance and distribute your application’s read traffic among them. **You can also create a read replica from another read replica**"